# Unable to submit contact form from mobile device

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am able to submit my the contact form in the footer on desktop version but not on mobile. "Send message" button below the contact form is not clickable on mobile. My website link: https://expatguideturkey.com/ Below is my code for this form. Please advise.

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-4"
  data-sal="slide-up"
  data-sal-delay="300"
  data-sal-duration="60s"
  data-sal-easing="ease">
    <h3>PROFESSIONAL ASSISTANCE</h3>
    <p className="expat-contact">Some Paragraph... </p>          
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-1"><br/></div>
  <div className="col-md-7"
  data-sal="slide-up"
  data-sal-delay="400"
  data-sal-duration="60s"
  data-sal-easing="ease">
    <h3>GET IN TOUCH</h3>
    <form 
    name="contact" 
    method="POST" 
    action="https://getform.io/f/192e20fe" 
    >

      <div className="half left cf">
        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" className="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required /> 
        <input type="email" name="email" id="input-email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" title="Email (format: your@example.com)" required  />
        <div className="invalid-feedback">
          Please enter a valid email address.
        </div>
        <div style={{ paddingTop: '5px'}}>
          <select name="service" id="service" className="form-control" v-model="service" style={{ color:'crimson' }}>
            <option>General Enquiry</option>
            <option>Citizenship Application</option>
            <option>Residence Permit Application</option>
            <option>Work Permit Application</option>
            <option>Company Establishment</option>
            <option>Virtual and Ready Office</option>
            <option>Umbrella Services</option>
          </select> 
        </div>
        <IntlTelInput fieldId="phonenum" fieldName="phonenum" containerClassName="intl-tel-input" inputClassName="form-control" defaultCountry="tr"/>
      </div>
      <div className="half right cf">
        <textarea name="message" id="input-message" rows="4" className="form-control"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>

      <input type='submit' id="input-submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the Gatsby plugin that I am using for animation:

```
   `gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal`,
      options: {
          threshold: 1, // Percentage of an element's area that needs to be visible to launch animation
          once: true, // Defines if animation needs to be launched once
          disable: false, // Flag for disabling animations

          // Advanced Options
          selector: '[data-sal]', // Selector of the elements to be animated
          animateClassName: 'sal-animate', // Class name which triggers animation
          disabledClassName: 'sal-disabled', // Class name which defines the disabled state
          rootMargin: '0% 50%', // Corresponds to root's bounding box margin
          enterEventName: 'sal:in', // Enter event name
          exitEventName: 'sal:out' // Exit event name
      }
    },
```

Below is the css of the above form:

```
form {
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-height: 150PX;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
form input, form textarea {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0.7em;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  resize: none;
}
form input:focus, form textarea:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px #e74c3c !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px #e74c3c !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 2px #e74c3c !important;
}

.form-control input:focus{
  background-color: rgb(255, 218, 232);

}

form #input-submit {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(221, 59, 59, 0.863);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 295px;
  height: 50px;
 }
form #input-submit:hover {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 2px #d22e !important;
  background: #d22e;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

form #input-message{
  height: 145px;
}

form textarea {
  height: 115px;
  width: 370px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `div.col-md-4` elements are overlapping the "Send Message" button.

[image: Element Overlapping]

<s>A quick fix would be to add the `pointer-events: none` CSS property to the elements, this allows you to click through the element. Since that seems like kind of a hacky solution to me, and not your intended behaviour,</s> I'd suggest fixing the layout and hiding the elements in the mobile view. This is up to you to decide as I have no idea what your intention is.

EDIT: I looked into your layout, and it seems like you're misusing the column layout a little bit. I wouldn't suggest putting line breaks in empty columns.

Anyways, the solution is to remove the `max-height` property from your `form` in the CSS. The `max-height` pushes the `textarea` and message button outside of the form and allows the column to overlap them.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you also check my css is this causing this column overlap. The text area is also not accessible from mobile.

Comment: anyone can suggest any solution. I applied pointer-events:none; css to the column which was overlapping but its still same.

Comment: I removed the max-height css property from my form and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot for your assistance.